# iOS8 in-app purchasing broken?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to get in app purchasing to work properly in the simulator however after the prompt is provided by Storekit that says "Use Existing Account?", the textfields cannot be filled in. They appear to have a black border around them and no matter what the keyboard does not appear. I cannot even type into them so its not related to activating the software keyboard.

Anybody know what could be going on? I am currently on XCode 6 Beta 5.

Here is an image of the behaviour:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQWqk.jpg

Edit: Also there is absolutely no error.

Comment: Hello In AppPurchase it will work on only real device sometime it will work on simulater also but you have check compulsary in real device..

Comment: u r using xcode 6 beta version only it wont work some time xcode beta version wait until sep 9th releasing original xcode 6 after that u check it it will work..